# Insurance Quote Programme

Tags: c#

I'm really new to this and as part of a school assignment I have to make a programme that will give an insurance quote based on different variables such as age and gender. We have gotten most of the code working but now we need to get the quote to increment each time a specific thing is input such as gender. It outputting the information but the quote variable isn't going up. Any help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
namespace Insurance
{
    internal class Insurance
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nationwide Heath Insurance Co.\n");
#pragma warning disable CS0168
#pragma warning disable CS0165
#pragma warning disable CS8600
#pragma warning disable CS8321
#pragma warning disable CS0219
#pragma warning disable CS8601

            int CustomerID = 1;
            int Age;
            int Quote = 250;
            String Eir, Gender, FirstName, LastName, UserAge, ConditionStatus;
            bool ConditionBool, SmokingStatus = true;

            decimal CoverageAmount, BasePremiumRate, AgePremiumFactor,
            SmokingPremiumFactor, HealthConditionFactor, TotalPremium;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name:");
            FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your last name ");
            LastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your gender ");
            Gender = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Gender != "male" || Gender != "Male")
            {
                Convert.ToInt32(Quote + 250);
            }
            else if (Gender != "female" || Gender != "Female")
            {
                Convert.ToInt32(Quote + 175);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age");
            UserAge = Console.ReadLine();
            Age = Convert.ToInt32(UserAge);
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your adress (eircode)");
            Eir = Console.ReadLine();
#pragma warning disable CS8602
            Eir = Eir.ToUpper();
            string BadConditions = "Do you have any existing health conditions? ( y/n )";
            Console.WriteLine(BadConditions);
            ConditionBool = AskCondition(ref BadConditions);

            Console.WriteLine($"Quote ID: {CustomerID}\n");
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {FirstName} {LastName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Age: {Age}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Gender: {Gender}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Address: {Eir}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Health Conditions: {BadConditions}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Quote: {Quote}");
        }

        private static bool AskCondition(ref string BadConditions)
        {
            bool ConditionBool;
            while (true)
            {
                // Quote + 50%
                string ConditionAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
                if (ConditionAnswer != null && ConditionAnswer == "y")
                {
                    ConditionBool = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Please specify your health condition using a coma:");
                    BadConditions = Console.ReadLine();
                    string[] HealthConditions = new string[] { "" };
                    HealthConditions = BadConditions.Split(',');
                    break;
                }
                else if (ConditionAnswer != null && ConditionAnswer == "n")
                {
                    ConditionBool = false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Only y or n Allowed");
                }
            }

            return ConditionBool;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` is a function that return a value, you are not storing/assigning the result of that function call to any variable. Incidentally there is no need to call it (`Quote + 250` is already an integer)

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(Quote + 250);` doesn't make sense. You can simply add two integers together. Even if it did make sense you're not using the return value so it's like it never happened. It is entirely possible to write code with no warnings and not use `#pragma warning disable`. I suspect the warnings you are suppressing are actually important and you should pay attention to them and fix them.

Comment: BTW, another tip. If you need to add a bunch of warning disable sentences you are likely doing something wrong that you should understand

Comment: You would typically try to separate code handling user input from code handling business rules, such as calculating the quote. This tend to make the code easier to read, reuse and test. If you are new to programming I would highly encourage you to learn how to use the debugger, and to write unit tests. That makes it much easier to find bugs early, especially once the programs start getting a bit larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the lines of code:

```
    if (Gender != "male" || Gender != "Male")
    {
            Convert.ToInt32(Quote + 250);
    }
    else if (Gender != "female" || Gender != "Female")
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(Quote + 175);
    }
```

you are not actually assigning the return value of the conversion to a variable so Quote is never updating.

You could change the lines to include a unary operator:

```
Quote = Quote + Convert.ToInt32(value)
```

or

```
Quote += Convert.ToInt32(value)
```

Or you could create a new variable to track the change in value and use that for ouput:

```
result = Convert.ToInt32(Quote + value)
Console.WriteLine("Quote: {result}")
```

Comment: That worked I used first one. I also need to increase the quote by 20% if age is under 35, 40% if age is between 35 and 55 inclusive, and 65% if age is between 56 to 70 inclusive and no increase if 71 or higher. Id appreciate any suggestion on how to handle that also

Comment: You could write the code like you have for Gender but based on age input or you could write a separate method that takes the input age as an argument and returns an integer value (don't forget to assign the return value!)

Sort of along the lines of:
    `Quote += adjustQuoteForAge(int age)`

then wrap your multiplicative logic inside the method.

Comment: I would highly recommend watching some beginner tutorials for programming fundamentals and reading the c# documentation where relevant

Comment: Thanks you have been super helpful. I have a look at some tutorials. Just started a course in software development and been doing c# for a few weeks now

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! Keep it up! It's a long but rewarding road. If you could accept my answer and close the question that would be awesome!

Some tutorial sites:
CodeAcademy.com
learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/csharp-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners/
https://www.w3schools.com/cs/index.php

Comment: Adding: the string equality test would better be replaced by an overload that accepts options and there, set it to case insensitive. But: in this specific case, writing the whole word puts a lot of responsibility onto the user (believe me, it does). It's an "either-or" question. So ask for a single char. People will still mess up, though.